# Why is it inappropriate to place block-level elements inside anchor elements?

Tags: html

Why should we not use `<a><li>something</li></a>`? or something like `<a><div>something2</div></a>`?

Comment: Do you have a source where it is stated that we shouldn't?

Comment: Software development is already hard enough. Opting out from useful tools (such as HTML linters) and relying on all browsers applying the same fixes for invalid code is not going to help.

Comment: This sort of thing was discouraged (though still common) in html4; but it's no longer Considered Harmful.

Comment: @DanielBeck - A check using NVDA  with Firefox shows that `<a><li>something</li></a>` is indeed harmful. The list items are not identifiable to NVDA users.

Comment: @Alohci fair point -- I was speaking to the general case of block-level elements within an anchor tag; isherwood's answer below explains the specific case of `li` (which is due to nesting rules for list items, not the anchor itself afaik.)

Answer (score 2):

The first case is invalid because the only allowed child of a `ul` is `li`. It's simply invalid HTML structure.

The second case is valid and common in HTML5. Some documentation that discourages it refers to older specifications and practices.